# Internet status checking in android

Tags: android, android-layout, internet-connection

In my android application i am using lot of `AsyncTasks`.I want to check internet connection while running each Async Tasks.Can i create a common class and common `xml` layout for displaying "No connection" rather than checking each `AsyncTasks` execution?

Comment: why do u want it in asyntask , u can use broadcast reciever which wont block main ui thread

Comment: then how to know is net present or not while running asyntask..?

Comment: Instead create separate layout for it just try to display on AlertDialog.

Comment: @AswinNNair check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986588/7666442

Comment: @Nilu thanks i will try this

Comment: welcome @AswinNNair  happy to help you let me know if any query

Answer (score 0):

Just create a error layout  and include it to each xml .Or add it at runtime as you wish to do .

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/error_view"
    layout="@layout/view_error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

On any connection error make the error visible with specified message.There can be a retry button too.
Toggle the visibility of error view according to connection available. Checking network connection :-

```
 public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return true;
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```